# Using PrintTask a Map with Graphics symbols not solid

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I have a Web map using JavaScript API.  One of the layers is a Graphics Layer that I add graphics to.

The line symbol style for these graphics I add is STYLE_SHORTDOT.  When I have a graphics drawn on the map, the PrintTask task refuses to export the map.  (It works as long as that type of graphic is not on the map.)   All I have to do to get the PrintTask to like my graphics is use STYLE_SOLID.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?  Am I condemned to use only solid line graphics if I want to export my map?